# Automatically delete temporary files in Google Drive submitted by Google Form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a Google Form that is used internally within our Organization. It allows people to submit files. The files are placed into a folder based off the name of the question in the form. The problem is that when the form is loading the files, it stores them in the root folder of drive, then sends them. Most of the users don't know that it does this and therefore it keeps creating files in their drive. How can i use a script that would get permission from them the first time they use the form with the script and then every time thereafter that they use the form it submits the files then removes the temporary ones from their root folder?

I have found ways to delete files older than X amount of days, but I cannot find anything that shows anything about the temporary file that is created. That is the only information lacking.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question showing us what you have tried and any errors you are getting.

Comment: You will need to install an "On Form Submit" trigger, and write code to delete the file.  Explaining how to do all of that would take a lot of time and work.  There may be code somewhere that already does something similar.  There is no complete answer to your question because it is to broad.  If you want general advice on how to start this project, that is not what Stack Overflow is for.  If this is a project that you can not program yourself, you should try to hire someone.